# Make parameters available in an application

Tags: java, command-line-interface

What is the standard way of storing a command line argument so that it can be accessed when required?

I can see 2 scenarios:

1. The argument is consumed immediately (A logging level)
2. The argument is not needed immediately (On failure send email to address *X*)

With scenario 1 It would seem quite natural to configure it upfront, however when it is a scenario more in the vein of scenario 2 I would prefer to configure that component as and when necessary (IE not up front)

So to phrase the question slightly differently how do I make my configuration options available to my entire application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like that (you can store the CommandLine somewhere or use the opions right away):

```
Options options = createOptions();
CommandLineParser parser = new GnuParser();
CommandLine cmdLine;
int timeoutHumanMove;
try
{
    cmdLine = parser.parse(options, args, true);
    timeoutHumanMove = getTimeoutOption(cmdLine, "thm", 300);
}
catch(ParseException e)
{
    return;
}

private static int getTimeoutOption(CommandLine cmdLine, String opt, int defaultSeconds)
    throws ParseException
{
    if(cmdLine.hasOption(opt))
    {
        Number val = (Number)cmdLine.getParsedOptionValue(opt);
        return (int)(val.doubleValue() * 1000D);
    } else
    {
        return 1000 * defaultSeconds;
    }
}

private static Options createOptions()
{
    Options options = new Options();
    options.addOption(OptionBuilder.withDescription("print this help and exit").create(OptionBuilder.withLongOpt("help"), 104));

    // ...
    return options;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have a singleton `Configuration` object, in which all relevant things are stored.

```
public class Configuration {
  private static final Configuration conf = new Configuration();

  public static Configuration get() {
    return conf;
  }

  private String failureEmailAddress;
  public String getFailureEmailAddress() {
    return failureEmailAddress;
  }

  public void parseCommandLine(String[] args) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to store application wide configuration information such as you describe. However, most of the time you store it in a class which is specific to the job (ApplicationContext), and then the instance is passed into the other classes as parameters or in a constructor or something like that. I usually make the ApplicationContext immutable.

Some applications I've come across use a static global context, effectively a global variable. This isn't necessarily a good idea, for the same reason that you should avoid global variables.

However, I would say that you should always verify that the command line options are valid up front. You don't want to do 3 hours of processing and then find out that someone hadn't configured the email address correctly on the command line. This should be a fail-fast situation.

Answer (score -1):

You could store your command args into System properties using System.setProperty() then you can access your properties anywhere via System.getProperty()..

Comment: Could someone help me understand.. is it a bad practice to use System properties in this manner? If it is, why is it? Just thought I'll understand it better so that I dont use it in my coding from here on.